# Any way to get Jenkins Git commits with Clubhouse tags to link to the Clubhouse story?

Tags: git, jenkins, github, jenkins-plugins, clubhouse

We've moved from JIRA to Clubhouse and miss the Github commit links to the JIRA items when a [FOO-1234] was in the commit. We'd like the same for [ch1234]. Is there a plugin or some other technique to do this?

Answer (score 0):

There is but it is in Github rather than Jenkins
It is called autolinking references.  You can find it in the repo settings

see https://github.blog/2019-10-14-introducing-autolink-references/

So for Jira I add

```
ENG-
https://<MYSERVER>/browse/ENG-<num>
```